# combine avro files into one

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, avro

I want to combine small avro files into one avro file, keeping the same schema, using pig.

I tried to do this:

```
REGISTER avro-1.7.2.jar

a = load '$SOURCE' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage ();
store a into '$TARGET' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage ();
```

but failed with following error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

How do I combine small avro files into one file using pig ?

Comment: Your issue is not about combining the 2 files, but is about not resolving AvroStorage() correctly. Are you sure avro jar is present in correct location? Perhaps specifying the fully qualified path of the jar might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, AvroStorage is part on piggybank, so you need also to register piggybank.jar.

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar
```

Secondly, using AvroStorage request additional libraries so you need to register json-simple-1.1.1.jar.

```
REGISTER json-simple-1.1.1.jar
```

Thirdly, if you want use more recent version of Avro, you need avro-mapred.jar

I have following code in my Pig scripts:

```
REGISTER lib/piggybank-0.13.0.jar;
REGISTER lib/avro-1.7.7.jar;
REGISTER lib/avro-mapred-1.7.7.jar;
REGISTER lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar;
```